# WPF Contacts Manager

Tags: wpf, contacts

I need for a ready-to-use WPF contacts manager with source code (possibly in C#).
Incredibly, the web seems to be very poor on that side.
I've found these links for interesting implementation:

- http://www.johnstagich.com/WPF/publish.htm -> No source code available
- http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-model-view-presenter -> source code broken link from undetermined time...

I don't need fireworks... just an implementation with basic contacts fields, able to manage some thousands of contacts and an embedded search engine.

I was initially tempted to use Microsoft LightSwitch, but it's already in Beta 1, and the intrinsic limitations of Silverlight made me change road.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not the answer you are looking for try using Karl Shifletts [Xaml Powertoys](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/xaml-power-toys/) to build simple data entry forms for you in WPF.